# image not display in php select statement

Tags: php, html, session, file-upload

i used code to upload image and it uploaded successfully in the external folder and database also display fine while using it on my system but not later working when i uploaded it to the server.

```
$temp=explode(".", $_FILES['myimage']['name']);
$newfile=round(microtime(true)).'.'.end($temp);

<img src='/document/".$_SESSION['image']."' class=''>
```

Comment: You should probably post more/all of your relevant code, as the sample you've included in your question really isn't enough to help diagnose the issue right now.

Comment: Not clear on what's not working, is the image data coming back but not rendering correctly in a browser, or no data coming back at all?